# Remove duplicate documents using $first

Tags: mongodb

I previously composed a question but don't think I explained it that well, hence no responses. I am attempting again so that I can try and get it right.

I have an aggregation script that works except it doesn't account for duplicates. It also has a problem where I want to count the number of documents but due to an $unwind, I'm getting a count far higher than is true.

I am sharing my script with the problematic part commented out, a couple of example documents which are the same transaction but composed at different time and dates and some end results thus far with the script in its current state and what I hope to get.

The aggregation script first:

```
db.getCollection("9SP_Data").aggregate([



// find documents of a type and within a number range

{"$match" : {"_id.object_category" : "revenue-transaction"

        ,"_id.transaction_date": {

            $gte: 20160101000000,

            $lt: 20170101000000

            },

}},



/*

// sort into order so that if duplicates, the new document listed at top

{$sort : { "_id.connection":1,

       "_id.company":1,

       "_id.transaction_reference":1, 

       "object_creation_date": -1 }},



// only use first record to avoid duplicate records

{$group : { "_id" : ["$_id.transaction_refererence", "$_id.connection","$_id.object_origin","$_id.object_origin_category", "$_id.transaction_date"],

        "transaction_status" : {$first: "$_id.transaction_status"},

        "line_items" : {$first: "$line_items"}}},

*/



    {"$unwind" :  "$line_items"},

    {"$match"  :  {"line_items.item_category":"sales-revenue"}},

    {"$group" : {

       "_id":

           {

            "company" : "$_id.connection",

            "sum_by_date":  {$trunc:{ $divide: ["$_id.transaction_date", 100000000 ]}},

            //  10000000000 - by year

            //  100000000 - by month

            //  1000000 - by date

            //  10000 - by hour

            //  100 - by minute

            "category" : "$line_items.item_category",

            "origin_category" : "$_id.object_origin_category",

            "object_origin_type" : "$_id.object_origin_type",

            "object_origin" : "$_id.object_origin"

           },

        "metric_value"  : { $sum: "$line_items.item_net_total_value" },



        // count number of documents (I think this is counting line_items but I need number of distinct documents by _id.transaction_reference)

        "metric_volume":{$sum:1}}

},



// format the output to include the following values

{$project : {

"_id.company"               : "$_id.company",

"_id.metric_name"           : {$literal : "revenue"},

"_id.metric_category"       : {$literal : "sales"},

"_id.metric_type"           : {$literal : "month"},

"_id.metric_lookup"         : "$_id.sum_by_date",

"_id.object_origin_category": "$_id.origin_category",

"_id.object_origin_type"    : "$_id.object_origin_type",

"_id.object_origin"         : "$_id.object_origin",

"metric_value"              : "$metric_value",

"metric_volume"             : "$metric_volume"

}}

])
```

The result of this currently looks like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : {
    "company" : "2f758916-2eb1-4d95-a3bb-7d6258bc2143",
    "metric_name" : "revenue",
    "metric_category" : "sales",
    "metric_type" : "month",
    "metric_lookup" : 201602,
    "object_origin_category" : "point-of-sale",
    "object_origin_type" : "offline",
    "object_origin" : "vend"
},
"metric_value" : 403.3333,
"metric_volume" : 6
},

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : {
    "company" : "2f758916-2eb1-4d95-a3bb-7d6258bc2143",
    "metric_name" : "revenue",
    "metric_category" : "sales",
    "metric_type" : "month",
    "metric_lookup" : 201609,
    "object_origin_category" : "point-of-sale",
    "object_origin_type" : "offline",
    "object_origin" : "vend"
},
"metric_value" : 370,
"metric_volume" : 5
},

/* 3 */
{
"_id" : {
    "company" : "2f758916-2eb1-4d95-a3bb-7d6258bc2143",
    "metric_name" : "revenue",
    "metric_category" : "sales",
    "metric_type" : "month",
    "metric_lookup" : 201601,
    "object_origin_category" : "point-of-sale",
    "object_origin_type" : "offline",
    "object_origin" : "vend"
},
"metric_value" : 1140.0001,
"metric_volume" : 18
},

/* 4 */
{
"_id" : {
    "company" : "cb1c4a56-1544-4e9d-a433-abb33429a300",
    "metric_name" : "revenue",
    "metric_category" : "sales",
    "metric_type" : "month",
    "metric_lookup" : 201605,
    "object_origin_category" : "point-of-sale",
    "object_origin_type" : "offline",
    "object_origin" : "vend"
},
"metric_value" : 2618.1821,
"metric_volume" : 20
}
```

Once I have the duplicates handles through a $sort and $group, I would hope that out of the following two documents, a $project as described above might only use the latest record using the $first function.

```
{
"_id" : {
    "connection" : "cb1c4a56-1544-4e9d-a433-abb33429a300",
    "transaction_date" : 20171129170558,
    "transaction_date_utc" : "2017-11-29 17:05:58",
    "object_class" : "goods-service-transaction",
    "object_category" : "revenue-transaction",
    "object_type" : "receipt",
    "object_origin_category" : "point-of-sale",
    "object_origin_type" : "offline",
    "object_origin" : "vend",
    "transaction_status" : "OPEN",
    "related_reference" : "85"
},
"object_creation_date" : "20181210010904",
"party_identifier" : "WALKIN",
"staff_identifier" : "02dcd191-ae2b-11e6-f485-7967ed9c6343",
"staff_name" : "uat1@9spokes.com",
"line_items" : [
    {
    "item_name" : "Summer Dress / 10",
    "item_system_id" : "02dcd191-ae20-11e6-f485-7967ee5a21ee",
    "item_identifier" : "10017",
    "item_category" : "sales-revenue",
    "item_type" : "goods-service",
    "item_quantity" : 1,
    "item_net_unit_sale_value" : 102.2727,
    "item_net_unit_discount_value" : 0,
    "item_unit_tax_value" : 11.3636,
    "item_net_total_value" : 102.2727,
    "item_total_tax_value" : 11.36364,
    "item_total_gross_value" : 113.63636
},
    {
    "item_name" : "Dress Shirt / Polyester / Medium",
    "item_system_id" : "02dcd191-ae20-11e6-f485-7967eee35001",
    "item_identifier" : "10023",
    "item_category" : "sales-revenue",
    "item_type" : "goods-service",
    "item_quantity" : 1,
    "item_net_unit_sale_value" : 61.3636,
    "item_net_unit_discount_value" : 0,
    "item_unit_tax_value" : 6.8182,
    "item_net_total_value" : 61.3636,
    "item_total_tax_value" : 6.81818,
    "item_total_gross_value" : 68.18182
}
]
},
{
"_id" : {
    "connection" : "cb1c4a56-1544-4e9d-a433-abb33429a300",
    "transaction_date" : 20171129170558,
    "transaction_date_utc" : "2017-11-29 17:05:58",
    "object_class" : "goods-service-transaction",
    "object_category" : "revenue-transaction",
    "object_type" : "receipt",
    "object_origin_category" : "point-of-sale",
    "object_origin_type" : "offline",
    "object_origin" : "vend",
    "transaction_status" : "CLOSED",
    "related_reference" : "85"
},
"object_creation_date" : "20181210120904",
"party_identifier" : "WALKIN",
"staff_identifier" : "02dcd191-ae2b-11e6-f485-7967ed9c6343",
"staff_name" : "uat1@9spokes.com",
"line_items" : [
    {
    "item_name" : "Summer Dress / 10",
    "item_system_id" : "02dcd191-ae20-11e6-f485-7967ee5a21ee",
    "item_identifier" : "10017",
    "item_category" : "sales-revenue",
    "item_type" : "goods-service",
    "item_quantity" : 1,
    "item_net_unit_sale_value" : 102.2727,
    "item_net_unit_discount_value" : 0,
    "item_unit_tax_value" : 11.3636,
    "item_net_total_value" : 102.2727,
    "item_total_tax_value" : 11.36364,
    "item_total_gross_value" : 113.63636
},
    {
    "item_name" : "Dress Shirt / Polyester / Medium",
    "item_system_id" : "02dcd191-ae20-11e6-f485-7967eee35001",
    "item_identifier" : "10023",
    "item_category" : "sales-revenue",
    "item_type" : "goods-service",
    "item_quantity" : 1,
    "item_net_unit_sale_value" : 61.3636,
    "item_net_unit_discount_value" : 0,
    "item_unit_tax_value" : 6.8182,
    "item_net_total_value" : 61.3636,
    "item_total_tax_value" : 6.81818,
    "item_total_gross_value" : 68.18182
}
]
}
```

I expect only the last example document to be used (based on object_creation_date) in the sum by the group from transaction_date of 201812.

I also want metric_volume to count of 1 document not 2 which is the number of line_items as per $unwind.

Thanks for your help. Matt

Comment: just one point, I know _id.company doesn't exist, but it eventually will and shouldn't affect this challenge. Thanks

Comment: You are still forgetting this point [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Anthony, you're right, but after reading that, I cannot imagine providing any less information than I have. I tried to show the problem piece is commented out which is all of 5 lines which are either in the wrong place or formatted incorrectly and then an example data set of two documents and the current results. How can that be wrong? kind regards, Matt

Comment: Code is not formatted. Post only that much code where you got stuck.